# Eclipse Neon shows entities relationships twice

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I am trying to generate the `eclipselink-orm.xml` in a `Spring-Boot` application, by using the following menu in eclipse:

[image]

But sadly it shows each relationship between entities two times (double) which is wrong!

[image]

It is not even possible to remove them, even when I select the row the remove button is deactivated!

I am using Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3). How can I solve it?

Comment: Your Eclipse version is 3 years and 9 releases behind. Are there reasons to do retrocomputing or is this just wasting time?

Comment: I will try to update. However I don't thing it is related to the version of the eclipse. Because if I make a new project it will generate the file correctly. I think something related to setting of my project and I don't know the reason behind.

Comment: @howlger By updating eclipse the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By updating eclipse the problem resolved.